# How to segregate values in csv file which has duplicates without using modules in python

Tags: python

i have a csv file with raw data column a=city, b=country, c=population, d=continent. I want to aggregate the population country wise, how can i write without using modules like csv and pandas. i managed to write below code to separate the values as country and populatoin, net i would like to seggregate it to find the population country wise how can i do>

```
`
with open ("f:/March2020/12-Apr-2020/countrydata.csv", 'r') as file:
    result=[]
    population=(result,value)
    for line in file:
        words=line.split(',')
        result.append([(words[2]),(words[3])])
        value.append(words[3])

    #print(result,value)
    print(result)
`
```

Comment: what is value here?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid modules? At least the modules in the python standard library should be available everwhere you can run python in the first place. The csv module in particular takes work off your shoulder for parsing CSV. Especially with quotes, rolling your own parsing is worse in almost all circumstances. Anyway, the code above isn't complete, it seems. Where is ```value``` defined? Also an excerpt of the CSV file would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you want to use modules, If any problem in that, tell us about it?

Well, something like this:

```
with open('demo.csv', 'r') as file:
    withContinent,withCountry = [],[]
    # population=(result,value)
    for line in file:
        words=line.split(',')
        withContinent.append([(words[1]).rstrip(),(words[2]).rstrip()])
        withCountry.append([(words[2]).rstrip(),(words[3]).rstrip()])

    #print(result,value)
    print(withContinent)
    print(withCountry)
```

Comment: i am at beginner stage wanted to know how modules work, so wanted to work without modules.

Comment: Yes, the answer doesn't use any module.